# How to change the default "today" date in the WPF Calendar control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, calendar

Is there a way to change the current date to some date other then today in the standard WPF Calendar control?

Using the below bindings (VS 2010) for an MVVM project, the month being displayed correctly aligns with the DisplayDate. However, the grayed out date representing "today" remains the same and only grays out when the calendar is moved to the same month as "today" resides in.

```
  <Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding RTO.SelectedDate}" 
            DisplayDate="{Binding Path=RTO.DisplayDate}"
            Margin="151,122,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="205" />
```

What I would like to do is change the current date of the calendar in the viewmodel from its default of `DateTime.Today` to some other date. Can this be done? (I'd like the `SelectedDate` to remain whatever the user selects. That is, the `selecteddate` is not necessarily the current date).

(If this is a duplicate question, I apologize. But everything I've googled seems to use the `selecteddate` as the "currentdate").

Answer (score -1):

Please add **IsTodayHighlighted="False"** attribute to the control. Hope it will work.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-datepicker/

Comment: Setting IsTodayHighlighted="False" seems to turn off the graying of today's date, but does not show a "gray" box for any date I can find :( . Ideas?

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve the downvotes. Quite obviously this is the first step. The second step is to use the selected date highlighting for whatever you wish to accomplish.